# How to force make to spawn jobs only for recursions

Tags: makefile, qmake

I'm working on a huge project based on Qt, which take a couple of hours to compile even on a 6 cores machine.

The reason for this is that when I run `make` only one of the cores compile the sources: the others remain idle.

The solution would be to execute `make` with the `-j` option (something like `make -j6`), using all the 6 cores of my machine.

The problem with this is that the `make` do not spawn in a recursion.

For example:

I have 4 modules, A, B, C and D:
- D depends on A, B and C.
- B depends on A.
- C depends on system libraries only.
- A depends on system libraries only.

The `qmake` app generated a Makefile for each of the above modules and one Makefile to compile all the modules.

When I run `make -j6`, the 6 jobs start compiling all the modules, instead of compiling one  by one. This behavior is problem because when the module D must be linked against the other modules, those might not be ready, throwing a `not found` error.

Is it possible to change this behavior with a `make` option? Might this be a problem of software engineering (the modules are not well projected)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally discovered how to do this automatically with `qmake`.

It couldn't be simpler: just add `CONFIG += ordered` to the `.pro` file and everything will just work. More about this flag here at the [qmake Variable Reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#config).

Note that it only works with the `subdirs` project template, but this is not an issue since the parallel compilation is only an issue when you have dependency between different binaries.

Example:

```
# ABC.pro

TEMPLATE = subdirs

CONFIG += ordered

SUBDIRS += \
    A \
    B \
    C
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have missing dependencies between the recursive make invocations.  You haven't shown us the toplevel makefile that invokes the recursive makes, but I guess it looks something like this:

```
all: A B C D

A B C D:
    $(MAKE) -C $@
```

You can fix this by adding the necessary dependencies between the recursive makes:

```
all: A B C D

A B C D:
    $(MAKE) -C $@

B: A

D: A B C
```

This strategy will give you correct parallel builds, although at the cost of some performance -- there is a lot of work that *can* be safely parallelized between those submakes, and its a shame to serialize all of it just for the sake of the one or two commands in each that really have to be serialized.  A better solution is to use non-recursive make, which would require a more serious refactoring of your makefiles, or to use [Electric Make](http://www.electric-cloud.com/eade), which can solve this problem for you without requiring you to change the makefiles at all (not even to add the extra dependencies).  I've written about how [Electric Make fixes recursive make](http://blog.melski.net/2012/09/04/fixing-recursive-make/) on my blog.

*(Disclaimer: I'm the architect of Electric Make)*

Comment: That might be indeed the problem. But since I'm using `qmake` to generate the Makefiles, I don't want to manually edit the Makefiles. Anyway, I'll take a look into what `qmake` is generating.

Answer (score 1):

Try building with [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/).  That will unravel the recursion (see [Recursive Make Considered Harmful](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/books/rmch/)) by piping the sub-make's targets back to the main process, as though the makefiles had been cleanly designed from the outset.

Then it will do its normal dependency analysis, not abstractly on a directory level, but by drilling down to the real per-file dependencies across your whole directory tree.  So it can parallelize the maximum that's safely possible.

Actually I don't know why cmake generates makefiles...  All they do is call cmake to do everything behind make's back.  So much so, that makepp has some special handling for cmake to avoid endless recursion, for dependencies that make oversees.  Now qmake is not exactly cmake, and I'd be delighted to hear if it's near enough to work!

Comment: I don't know why make does not already behave this way. I even don't see any need for changes at the makefiles or makefile generators. I'll take a look into it! Thank you very much for your reply!